# Codeignite: Routes stop to working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

After I implementation assets in my Code, my routes stopped to work..

So the only thing I did was change my .htaccess, i added **"|assets|"** and it was enough to "break" my routes in this and other projects.. I cant delete this project and start a new

```
RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Routes:

```
$route['indicacao'] = "indicacao";
$route['projeto'] = "projeto";
$route['logout'] = "home/logout";
$route['login'] = "home/login";
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: what is location of your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following .htaccess rules for CodeIgniter:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

1. It prevents access to /system and /application directories.
2. Enables access for all the physically existing files/directories.
3. Redirects all the rest virtual routes to CI.

Comment: Nice, but this not solved my problem, still not work, Always i configure my Assets, routes stop to working

Comment: hmm no idea... are you sure name is correct and you use latin only?

Comment: Portugueses..yeah! it's right, all my routes were working until i implement assets! This is second project that i do! The first happened same thing